# Как разделить List<> на sublist

Tags: c#, list, split

Есть `List<int>`. Как разделить его по элементу 6666? Засплитить так сказать.

```
1
2
3
6666
4
5
6
6666
7
8
9
6666
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static List<List<T>> SplitBy<T>(List<T> source, T separator)
{
    int c = 0;
    return
        source
            .GroupBy(val => separator.Equals(val) ? ++c : c)
                .Select(g => g.Skip(Math.Min(g.Key, 1)).ToList())
                    .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Как у вас так хорошо получается)?

Comment: @mehelta пятница же :) на самом деле просто спер идею [с реализации на F#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6737659/1988244), которую когда-то выгуглил для личных целей

Comment: Эээ... Это предполагает, что (1) `GroupBy` просматривает элементы и вычисляет ключ лишь один раз, (2) что группы лежат в том же порядке, что и в исходном списке. Кроме того, это вылетит, если `separator == null`.

Comment: @VladD да. в живом проекте я бы такое не стал использовать. взял бы нормальный код с yield

Comment: @VladD кстати (2) гарантируется - The IGrouping<TKey, TElement> objects are yielded in an order based on the order of the elements in source that produced the first key of each IGrouping<TKey, TElement>. и очень сомнительно чтобы (1) зачем-то нарушалось - просто потому, что смысла дважды вычислять ключ для элемента, котрый уже был yield-ну в результат - нет.

Comment: @PashaPash: Ну, классическая реализация quicksort ведь вызывает сравнивающую функцию много раз. Если бы `GroupBy` просто сортировал по ключу с сравнивающей функцией `(x, y) => compare(keySelector(x), keySelector(y))`, `keySelector` вызывался бы много раз. Это по идее валидная реализация. Кешировать вычисленные ключи может быть невыгодно из-за расхода памяти, кстати. [Для обеспечения (2) достаточно взять любую стабильную сортировку.]

Comment: > Кешировать вычисленные ключи может быть невыгодно из-за расхода памяти - какой еще расход памяти? ключи же все равно отдаются на выходе, как часть групинга. и да, сортировка - это не валидная реализация - я же процитировал выше msdn - GroupBy не сортирует по значению ключа )

Comment: @PashaPash: Ну, ключи-то отдаются, но как часть группы — то есть, один на группу. Если у вас очень много элементов, всего пара групп, и огромные ключи, кеширование ключей может быть невыгодно. А где в MSDN написано, что реально под капотом не имеет право быть сортировка? Я не нашёл этого в вашей цитате.

Comment: @VladD groupby отдает данные с сохранением оригинального порядка (и порядка групп, и внутри группы (об этом тоже есть в msdn)).  и тот же msdn упоминает что для сравнения используется default equality comparer (который не слишком удобен для сортировки). Можно предположить, что там под капотом есть сортировка. которая ничего не делает, и которую туда вписал засланый агент java, чтобы C# был медленнее чем должен быть. Но я бы не стал такое предполагать )

Comment: @PashaPash: Почему же? Стабильная сортировка по ключу даст именно такой результат, за то же время O(n log n). (Быстрее, по очевидным причинам, невозможно.)

Comment: @VladD **сортировка** по ключу даст на выходе **неотсортированный** список групп?

Comment: @VladD `(new int[] {1,3,2}).GroupBy(k => k).Select(k => k.Key).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);` [выдает](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) 1, **3**, 2 - и это задокументированное поведение. А теперь попробуйте поставить заменить GroupBy на сортировку, причем так, чтобы результат остался тот же.

Comment: @PashaPash: Мне как-то неохота спорить о том, что полагаться на детали конкретной имплментации — не лучшая идея. Подумайте, почему вам понадобился `ToList()`.

Comment: @VladD Я прекрасно знаю зачем там ToList(). и я как бы и не спорю что завязываться на реализацию - плохо. Причем прямо написал об этом выше.  Да, если кто-то решит вызвать keySelector у уже обработанного элемента-сепаратора, все поломается. Я просто не понимаю как можно  впихнуть в реализацию GroupBy сортировку, при этом не поменяв порядок ни самих групп, ни элементов внутри групп. Хотелось бы увидеть пример конкретной имплементации с сортировкой внутри, раз вы считаете ее достаточно очевидной.

Comment: @PashaPash GroupBy есть изменение порядка, поэтому самоочевидно, что это является некоторой сортировкой. Ну вот вам пример: http://ideone.com/6lvylx Все операции, кроме сортировки, O(n).

Comment: @PashaPash: Или так: http://ideone.com/iQFF2H Сложный компаратор нужен лишь для обеспечения стабильности сортировки. // Ага, OrderBy гарантирует стабильную сортировку, так что достаточно такого: http://ideone.com/I06cYS

Comment: @VladD Ок, согласен, GroupBy действительно можно реализовать с помощью двойного пробега по source, сортировки, двойного вычисления ключей, и двойного-тройного копирования данных (там же еще должно быть разрезание на окончательные группы). Вопреки здравому смыслу. Просто из злости на весь мир. Тупо перебор элементов и распихивание  их в Lookup - для слабаков, чьи Enumerable можно перебрать лишь один раз.

Comment: @PashaPash: Копирования данных там нет, по крайней мере для случая reference type'ов. В любом случае, код не имеет права исходить из недокументированных свойств конкретной имплементации, какими бы «самоочевидными» они не были. (Например, вычисление ключа ровно один раз нигде не гарантируется.)

Comment: @VladD я с этим согласился в 4-ом комменте сверху. и еще пару раз где-то посредине. в конкретной реализации может быть хоть сортировка, хоть форматирование диска. Что никак не отменяет того факта, что решение через GroupBy работает. И того, что при разработке надо писать тесты, чтобы не было сюрпризов при смене реализаций - мало ли, команда .net core наймет индуса, который найдет вашу реализацию и скопипастит ее в .NET 5.0 ))

Comment: @PashaPash: Кажется, мы залезли в оффтопик. Судя по всему, мы по-разному понимаем слово «работает».

Answer (score 3):

Например, так:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SplitBy<T>(T sep, IEnumerable<T> seq)
{
    List<T> currentPart = new List<T>();
    foreach (var value in seq)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(value, sep))
        {
            yield return currentPart;
            currentPart = new List<T>();
        }
        else
        {
            currentPart.Add(value);
        }
    }
    yield return currentPart;
}
```

---

Вы можете положить эту функцию в статический класс, объявить так:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SplitBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, T sep) { ...
```

и тогда можно будет использовать функцию следующим образом: `list.SplitBy("666")`. Спасибо @pavelip за подсказку.

Comment: не пашет http://pastebin.com/pMjPLvxX

Comment: Исправил ошибку.

Comment: @pavelip: Спасибо! Писал не тестируя.

Comment: А почему не написали экстеншен? Было бы на мой взгляд шоколаднее.

Comment: @pavelip: Я когда-то написал их такую кучу, что в проекте интеллисенс выдавал наверное миллионы, и среди них сложно было найти нужную — после чего я к ним (незаслуженно) охладел. Но вообще вы правы.